# Using plotly with zeppellin in scala

Tags: scala, histogram, plotly, apache-zeppelin

I want to display my results in the form of a histogram in Zeppelin. I came across plotly. My code is in scala and I would like to know the steps to incorporate plotly into zeppelin using scala. Or is there any better way(libraries) that can be used to draw a histogram in Zeppelin(Scala)?

Answer (score 5):

If you have a dataframe called plotTemp with columns "id","degree" then you can do the following:

1. In a scala window register the dataframe as a temporary table

`plotTemp.registerTempTable("plotTemp")`

2. Then switch to the SQL interpreter in a new window

   ```
   %sql
   select degree, count(1) nInBin
   from plotTemp
   group by degree
   order by degree
   ```

You can then click on the bar plot icon and you should see what you are looking for

[Example of distribution plot done in Zeppelin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfyIR.png)

Comment: the scale of the X-axis is compressed where you have no corresponding X-values. just look at your own graph and compare locations of x-values of 102 and 43828

Answer (score 4):

After trying basically every available solution I eventually settled for [vegas-viz](https://github.com/vegas-viz/Vegas). If you look at their project's page on GitHub, they claim to be "*The Missing MatPlotLib for Scala + Spark*". Although that sounds a little bit exaggerated to me at the moment, the library does its work and does it well.

This is the procedure I suggest for drawing a Bar Chart (that's what you need for histograms, basically) in the Zeppelin's Spark Interpreter:

1. import dependencies (please check the [vegas maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.vegas-viz) for the latest versions)

   ```
   %dep  
   z.load("org.vegas-viz:vegas_2.11:0.3.11")
   z.load("org.vegas-viz:vegas-spark_2.11:0.3.11")
   ```

Note that vegas-spark is needed only if you want to draw directly from a DataFrame, see below.

2. import packages

   ```
   import vegas._  
   import vegas.render.WindowRenderer._
   ```
3. draw chart

   ```
   val plot = Vegas("Sample Column Chart")
     .withData(
       Seq(
         Map("country" -> "USA", "population" -> 314),
         Map("country" -> "UK", "population" -> 64),
         Map("country" -> "DK", "population" -> 80)
       )
     )
     .encodeX("country", Nom)
     .encodeY("population", Quant)
     .mark(Bar)
   plot.show
   ```

   The result should be similar to the image below:

[image]

4. you can even draw an image directly from a DataFrame if you have added vegas-spark among the dependencies (see point 1.) but you also need an extra import for this to work:

   ```
   import vegas.sparkExt._

   val df = Seq(
     ("USA", 314),
     ("UK", 64),
     ("DK", 80)
   ).toDF("country", "population")

   val plot = Vegas("Sample Column Chart", width=600, height=320)
     .withDataFrame(df)
     .encodeX("country", Nom)
     .encodeY("population", Quant)
     .mark(Bar)
   plot.show
   ```

The result should be the same as above.

Answer (score 1):

I just released [spark-highcharts](https://github.com/knockdata/spark-highcharts). With following code, you can create a histogram.

```
import com.knockdata.spark.highcharts._
import com.knockdata.spark.highcharts.model._
highcharts(bank
    .series("x" -> "age", "y" -> count("*"))
    .orderBy(col("age"))
  )
  .chart(Chart.column)
  .plotOptions(new plotOptions.Column().groupPadding(0).pointPadding(0).borderWidth(0))
  .plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Import doesn't work. Perhaps leave a comment of how to get highcharts into the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the previous answers, if you have a dataframe called `tmp` you can just run the following

```
z.show(tmp)
```

this will produce the following and you can change the graphs by clicking on the upper left corner buttons

[image]